# Create PKCS7 for PDF signing

Tags: objective-c, pdf, openssl, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I'm trying to sign a PDF with certificate. I prepare the PDF for signing, generate SHA256 hash value of the document, encrypt it with my private key and now I need to create PKCS7 certificate. When I create it like this:

```
PKCS7 *pkcs7 = PKCS7_sign(certificate, privateKey, ca, fileBIO, PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_BINARY);
PKCS7_final(pkcs7, fileBIO, PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_BINARY);
```

the certificate works but it doesn't contain any hash value. How do I insert my custom SHA256 hash value?

Comment: I think you're best off to achieve that using the toolkit that generates the pdf, or any other toolkit handling pdfs and being able to sign them, though I've no idea about what would be usable there from obective-c I'm afraid.

Comment: @StefanHegny I'm using plugPDF framework but it doesn't provide methods for creating certificate.

Comment: [Pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/references.html) offers signing functionality. It is Java, but there is an article how to use it with objectiv-c.

Comment: I found a framework specifically made for handling certificates [link](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/). To generate a PKCS7 file I only needed their CRYPT license.